# Relation between height and volume of frustum

Tags: geometry, volume

Suppose I have a physical coffee mug that is in the shape of a frustum. I can find the physical dimensions like smallest and largest radius and the height of the frustum. My question is till what height should I fill my cup to get a specific volume of water in it. For example I want 150 ml of water inside my cup so what height do I fill it till.The radius of the liquid at this level is also not know by me.
A,B,C are all known.
X is unknown.
[Cup |Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80Xlv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume of a frustum is derived from that of a cone $Ah/3 = d^2h\pi/12$.

The frustum is just a cone that you have removed the tip from and the volume is the difference of the volume of the cone and the tip. Now you probably don't have the height of the cone and the tip so you will have to use the fact that the diameter varies linearily along the axis. The slope is $(D-d)/H$ where $D$ is the larger and $d$ is the smaller diameter and $h$ is the height of the frustum. This gives the that the height of the tip is $Hd/(D-d)$. So you have to calculate the difference of the cone formed by the liquid and the tip and the tip itself. What we need is to find the base diameter of that cone which is $d + h(D-d)/H$. Putting these together we get:

$$V = \left(\left(d+{h(D-d)\over H}\right)^2\left(h+{Hd\over D-d}\right)-d^2{Hd\over D-d}\right){\pi\over 12}$$

Where $d$ is the smaller diameter, $D$ is the larger, $H$ is the height of the frustum and $h$ is the depth of the liquid. The factor $\pi/4$ is because of circular base and could be changed if you desire another shape of the base.

If you want to solve for $h$ you may expand the expression:

$$V = \left(\left(d+{h(D-d)\over H}\right)^2\left(h+{Hd\over D-d}\right)-d^2{Hd\over D-d}\right){\pi\over 12}\\
= \left(\left(d^2+2d{h(D-d)\over H}+\left({h(D-d)\over H}\right)^2\right)\left(h+{Hd\over D-d}\right)-d^2{Hd\over D-d}\right){\pi\over 12} \\
= \left(
hd^2
+ h^2{2d(D-d)\over H}
+ h^3{(D-d)^2\over H^2} 
+ {Hd^3\over D-d}
+ 2hd^2
+ h^2{(D-d)d\over H}
- {Hd^3\over D-d}
\right){\pi\over 12} \\
= \left(
h^3{(D-d)^2\over H^2} 
+ 3h^2{(D-d)d\over H}
+ 3hd^2
\right){\pi\over 12} \\
= {(D-d)^2\over H^2}\left(
h^3
+ 3h^2{Hd\over (D-d)}
+ 3h \left({Hd\over (D-d)}\right)^2
+ \left({Hd\over (D-d)}\right)^3
- \left({Hd\over (D-d)}\right)^3
\right){\pi\over 12} \\
= {(D-d)^2\over H^2}\left(\left(
h + {Hd\over (D-d)}\right)^3- \left({Hd\over (D-d)}\right)^3\right){\pi\over 12}
$$

Which can be readily solved for $h$:

$$h = 
\sqrt[3]{
V{12\over\pi}{H^2\over(D-d)^2} + \left({Hd\over (D-d)}\right)^3} - {Hd\over (D-d)}$$

Comment: I have the radius of the whole cup but I dont have the radius of the liquid.Using your formula i can calculate the volume of the whole cup or find the height of the cup. But what i want is less than the total volume of the cup where the larger radius and height of the liquid both are not know.

Comment: @Zenoros The radius of the liquid is not required. The formula only requires the diameter of the top ($D$) and bottom ($d$) of the frustum, the height $H$ of the frustum and the height ($h$) or depth of the liquid.

Comment: @skyking OP also don't know the height of liquid $h$

Comment: @skyking The height or depth of the liquid is what is required by me.

Comment: Yes, but you know the volume so you solve for $h$ which I've updated the solution with.

Comment: Is there a way to find how the diameter varies? Does getting the radius at half the height of the total cup help?

Comment: @Zenoros I'm assuming it varies linearily along the axis, otherway it wouldn't be a frustum. I have the diameter at the top and the bottom so having the radius ($=(D+d)/4$) doesn't add anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the formula of volume of frustum (as @skyking mentioned) you can easily solve your problem$$V=\pi\frac{h}{3}(R^2+r^2+Rr)$$If you know the volume, and both radius greater and smaller, then $$h=\frac{3V}{\pi(R^2+r^2+Rr)}$$Put the values and get your answer

Comment: I dont know the larger radius. I just know two radius and height of the whole cup.

Comment: After your comment, I can only reach to this conclusion$$x(A^2+y^2+Ay)=\frac{V_1B(A^2+C^2+AC)}{V}$$$A,B,C,x$ as mentioned in your figure, $y$ being the radius of liquid,$V,V_1$ are initial and final volume respectively, there is one equation and two unknown ,$x~and~y$, so I am searching for another equation showing relation between $x~and~y$

Comment: Yeah, if the cone angle is known it can be solved but that is also not known.